# PHP Logout Script

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a PHP logout script, however, as soon as I implement it, the page just gets redirected to the page after login. Here is the code:

Connect.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "database_name", "database_pass") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error());

    if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) 
             $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
 ?>
```

Logout.php

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
setcookie($username, time()-3600);  
    header("Location: index.php");
    die;    
?> //immediately after here, instead of going to index.php(the login page), it goes straight to the page that would appear after if the user had logged in(control_panel.php).
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: *sets his cookie username to `root`*

Comment: You're better off finding a tutorial online of how to create an auth script.  As noted above by @Petah, your method is insecure.

Comment: is "the page that would appear after if the user had logged in" also `index.php`? If yes, you have to [disable browser caching](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-4124)

Comment: @Petah, what do you mean by "sets his cookie username to root"?

Comment: @user1340238, the cookies are stored and sent by the client. If you read the username from the cookie, then the client can send you any username he wants.

Comment: Did you enable Codeigniter's page caching? do you have any cached pages at `application/cache`? I had the same problem a while ago because of caching.

Comment: @AzizAG, did he mention he's using CodeIgniter somewhere and I didn't notice?

Comment: @Radu, would that be the correct way to read the username then?

Comment: @user1340238, you should use the session and store the username inside the session, since the session is stored on the server and the client has no access to it. If the username is not in the session, then you should authenticate the user and make him prove he's him (by matching his password for example). After he can prove his identity, then you can store the username in the session and later look it up. And as always, the golden rule is: never trust user input.

Comment: @Radu I shouldn't mention Codeigniter. I meant caching in general, sorry.

Comment: your cookie is not getting expired, read my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong I guess, the problem lies here..

In your logout.php you are expiring a cookie after you are unsetting your session, your cookie is not getting expired.

And in connect.php you are using this condition to set a session again and it sets because cookie is still in the user's browser

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) 
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
```

So Instead of doing this :

```
setcookie($username, time()-3600);
```

Do this :

```
 setcookie($username, "", time()-3600);
```

Comment: he's actually removing the cookie, since he's setting a time in past `time() - 3600`.

Comment: @AzizAG may be his cookie is lying in the browser or may be he must be setting a cookie on index.php

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this page: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/security-review-creating-secure-php.html

It goes through "Creating a Secure PHP Login Script" completely. Your current solution has many security issues.